# Jira - How to clone an existing dashboard

Tags: api, rest, clone, jira, dashboard

Im wondering if there is any way to clone an existing Jira Dashboard with rest api? 
Or if I can create one from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at JIRA REST API https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/ Currently it is not possible to clone or create dashboard using  REST API.

Comment: Thanks. We found an alternative way, we use SDK in JAVA.

Comment: @Sandy can you give some details how you did that?